# Array Size Returned by Split Function - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Here is what I have done so far.

```
Sub MP_division()

Worksheets(3).Activate    
Dim last_cell As Integer    
Dim platforms() As String    
Dim arr_size As Integer  

platforms = Split(Cells(2, 47), ", ")    
last_cell = Mid(Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Address, 4)    
arr_size = len(platforms) // is there something like this?    
For x = 1 To last_cell    
    For y = 1 To arr_size 
        //do something        
    Next        
Next   
End Sub
```

My question is, how may I get the array size(arr_size) that is returned by the split function, so that I could use in my for loop? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get length of array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574814/get-length-of-array)

Answer (score 17):

Consider abound using [LBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264295(v=office.15).aspx) and [Ubound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658(v=office.15).aspx):

```
Sub MP_division()
    Dim last_cell As Long
    Dim platforms() As String
    Dim x As Long, y As Integer

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
        platforms = Split(.Cells(2, 47), ", ")
        last_cell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 1 To last_cell
            For y = LBound(platforms) To UBound(platforms)
                'do something
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

**Btw**, [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278528(v=office.15).aspx) always returns *zero-based* array (starts from `0`, but not from `1`). Thats why I recomend you to use both, Ubound and Lbound.

**One more thing**, I've changed `Dim last_cell As Integer` to `Dim last_cell As Long`, since max value of `Integer` only `32767` and if the last row would be greater than `32767`, you would get an error with `Integer`.

And [**avoid using Select/Active statements**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10718179#10718179) (it's about `Worksheets(3).Activate`)

Answer (score 7):

VBA LBound and UBound return the first and the last array position, so the correct answer is:

```
size = UBound(myArray) - LBound(myArray) + 1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim first as integer
Dim last as integer
Dim arr() as string
Dim lengthOfArray as integer

'split your data and save it in arr'

first = LBound(arr)
last = UBound(arr)

lengthOfArray = last - first

msgbox lengthOfArray 'This will display the length of the array'
```

Comment: can you please explain more detail about your answer ?